# How to cat files in linux vertically?

Tags: linux, cat

I have n files containing one line and want to concatenate them:

*Input files:*

```
file_1
A B C

file_2 
1 2 3
```

*Desired console ouput result:*

```
A B C
1 2 3
```

**But with**:

```
$ cat file_1 file_2
```

*I get*:

```
A B C1 2 3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
echo | cat file_1 - file_2
```

Alternatively, terminate the last line of file_1 with a new-line symbol.

Yet another way:

```
$ echo > n
$ cat file_1 n file_2 n file_1 n file_2 n
A B C
1 2 3
A B C
1 2 3
```

Comment: that works for 2 files I have more than 2 files and I dont know how to  change this command

Comment: @shaq updated the answer for your case

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than 2 files, you can use a loop with the shell and use `echo` to insert a new line:

```
for f in file1 file2 file3; do cat "$f"; echo; done > output
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have two files, you could use `echo` to output a new line and put that between your two files like so:

```
echo | cat file1 - file2
```

Comment: no its more than 2 files sorry I should have mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i observe using `bash` shell on **Ubuntu 12.04**.

```
$ echo "1 2 3" > file1
$ echo "a b c" > file2
$ cat file1 file2
1 2 3
a b c
```

Separate distinct lines.

It looks like `echo` command ensures that proper terminated strings are written to both the files.

Comment: This is because `echo` adds a new-line for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `file1` is missing a newline at the end. So when you `cat` them, there's no newline printed to separate `file1` from `file2`.

You either need to modify `file1` to include a trailing newline or insert it in some other way.